# Arduino I2C Wire master available read outputs -1 255 if slave sends less bytes

Tags: arduino, i2c

i tried this example:
http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireRead

But if i send less than 6 bytes from the slave the master still tries to read all 6 bytes and then the read function outputs -1/255. So actually the available function is kinda useless in this case, i could rather use a for till 6.

Any idea what i am doing wrong or how i can solve this? I cannot simply just filter all 255 values because sometimes i send them. I just dont understand the library behaviour here.

Edit: The weird thing is the read function returns an int, not a byte. So i can see if its -1 or 255. And its definitly 255 instead of -1. If i try to read 7 times instead of using the available function the last reading then is -1. Does the slave send wrong bytes or do i maybe need a pullup or whats going on here?

My solution is to read until read is -1 instead of using the available function. But there must be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

While this seems akward, it is the expected behaviour. The I2C protocoll does not provide any means of the slave to end the requested transmission. 
The length is solely defined by the `quantity` parameter given to `Wire.requestFrom`. This way the master decides, and have to know, how much bytes the slave will send. `Wire.available` only signals if the previously given length is reached.

To provide variable length messages, you may chose a delimiter character, like `\0` for string transmissions, or prepend the message with a byte storing the number of bytes following and stop reading if the told amount is reached.